# Floating DIVs break design upon height change

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a couple of floating DIVs that I want to align next to each other. This is how it looks currently: http://jsfiddle.net/D8DdJ/1/

Now, whenever the content of one DIV extends the height, it breaks the design, as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/D8DdJ/2/

So I want to have the DIVs align next to each other even when the height of one of them is larger. **How do I achieve this?** I know that I can set a fixed `height` to the `inner` class, but I cannot predict the content of each DIV because they are user submitted.

My CSS:

```
.container {
    border-top: 1px solid #F4F5F5;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 578px;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid #F4F5F5;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 170px;
}

.inner p {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="container">

   <div class="inner"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><img width="170" height="110" src="http://www.toyarena.com/images/sonic.jpg"></div>

   <div class="inner"><p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p><img width="170" height="110" src="http://www.toyarena.com/images/sonic.jpg"></div>

   <div class="inner"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><img width="170" height="110" src="http://www.toyarena.com/images/sonic.jpg"></div>

   <div class="inner"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><img width="170" height="110" src="http://www.toyarena.com/images/sonic.jpg"></div>

   <div class="inner"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><img width="170" height="110" src="http://www.toyarena.com/images/sonic.jpg"></div>

   <div class="inner"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><img width="170" height="110" src="http://www.toyarena.com/images/sonic.jpg"></div>

</div>
```

**EDIT:** Also, the number of DIVs in a row will change later, the container will be set to **100% width**, so adding a `clear:both` on each row will not work when not knowing the length of the row...

Answer (score 1):

could use `display:inline-block` instead of floating the .inner [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8DdJ/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/D8DdJ/8/

```
.container {
    border-top: 1px solid #F4F5F5;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid #F4F5F5;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 170px;
}
```

I just removed "float:left;" and added "display:inline-block;" and I also removed the width of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the .inner to `display: inline-block;` (remove the float) and for bonus points, throw a `vertical-align: top;` on the .inner to make it look nicer, IMO.

Here's the updated [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/D8DdJ/7/)